# Finding the state space representation of a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, state-space

I want to find the state space equations for the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1r9Be.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The equations I find are:

1. Ir = I1 + I2 = (U-Vn)/2
2. I2 = I3
3. I1 = 2*X1'
4. I2 = 1*X2'
5. I3 = 3*X3'
6. -X1 = X2+X3
7. Y = X3

Plugging in (3) and (4) to (1) I get:
(U+X1)/2 = 2*X1'+ X2'

I need to decouple the derivatives, but I don't see a relation that can do that.

Comment: What are you considering your state? What is it dimension?

Comment: I consider the voltages across my capacitors my states. Respectively they're X1,X2,X3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current going through \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ is the same, so, by,
$$ Q = Cv \leftrightarrow  i=C\dot{v}$$
For that branch,

$$\frac{\dot{v_3} - \dot{v_2} }{C_2} = \frac{-\dot{v_3}}{C_3}.$$

Also, the current that goes through the resistor either goes through \$C_1\$ or the branch with \$C_2, C_3\$. By associating them in series and then parallel, we find that,

$$\frac{v_1 - v_2 }{R} = \frac{ \dot{v_2}}{C_1+(C_2^{-1}+C_3^{-1})^{-1}}.$$

I did not go through the whole process of figuring out the state equations, but these should show that \$\dot{v_3} = k \dot{v_2}\$, those derivatives are related by a constant.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that in the current equation for C2 you can write it as i = C2*(V2') = C2*(-V1-V3)'= -C2*(V1'+V3').